# PHP - sem_get undefined runnin on linux CentOs

Tags: php, linux, mutex, semaphore

I'm having this error

```
Call to undefined function sem_get()
```

It is running on PHP Version 5.3.27, Apache/2.2.15 and CentOS.

I can't find a reason for this, also we have a testing server with (almost) the same setup and it is working fine (maybe different PHP extensions because we use this server with other projects too).

The test that I am running is the following:

```
<pre>
starts
<?
try {

    echo "instance\n";
    $mutex = new Mutex(633);
    echo "Acquire \n";
    $mutex->Acquire();
    echo "\n\n Atomic magic \n\n";
    echo "release \n";
    $mutex->Release();
    echo "null \n";
    $mutex = null;
    echo "end \n";

}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e;
    echo "\n<hr>\n";
    var_dump(error_get_last()); 
}
```

And the class Mutex is the following:

```
<?php
class Mutex
{
    protected $_Id;
    protected $_SemId;
    protected $_IsAcquired = false;

    /**
     * @param int $id Identifier of the Mutex, must be a number
     */
    function __construct($id)
    {
        if (!is_int($id))
        {
            throw new Exception('The Mutex identifier must be a number');
        }

        $this->_Id = $id;

        if (!($this->_SemId = sem_get($this->_Id, 1)))
        {
            throw new Exception('Error getting semaphore');
        }

    }

    public function Acquire()
    {
        if (!sem_acquire($this->_SemId))
        {
            throw new Exception('Error acquiring semaphore');
        }

        $this->_IsAcquired = true;
    }

    public function Release()
    {
        if (!$this->_IsAcquired)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!sem_release($this->_SemId))
        {
            throw new Exception('Error releasing semaphore');
        }

        $this->_IsAcquired = false;
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: are you sure it is installed? http://www.php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php use http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php

Comment: Seems that it is not loaded, thank you!